# Gets stuck loading a component that isn't logged in

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have a problem when redirecting when a user is not logged in. In my project I have two Guards for the Admin and User, then I use the functions of the @angular/fire/auth-guard library to redirect if logged in and if not. The problem is if I add my guards that I created myself, the guard that checks whether you are logged in or not of each component stops working, which keeps the page loading and never ends, instead mine does work . Here is an example of my code:

In this code that I have both the RolUserGuard and the RoleAdminGuard work, but the AuthGuard of home and admin do not work, they get caught loading without returning to the login page. Instead if you are logged in and try to redirect to the login page the AuthGuard works.

```
const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['']);
const redirectLoggedInToHome = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['home']);

const routes : Routes = [
  {path : '',redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path : 'login', component : LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {authGuardPipe: redirectLoggedInToHome}},
  {path : 'home', component : HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard,RoleUserGuard], data: {authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin} },
  {path : 'admin', component : AdminComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard,RoleAdminGuard], data: {authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin}, children:[
    {path : '', component : AdminUsersComponent},
    {path : 'user/:id', component: DetailsComponent}
  ]},
  {path : '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could it be because of the data property and that when adding a second Guard it does not detect it correctly? anything helps

I leave you the code of the other guards, although it is practically the same only that it changes instead of amin for user and vice versa.

```
  canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    
    const rol = localStorage.getItem('rolUser');

    if(rol!=='admin'){
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post RoleUserGuard and RoleAdminGuard, just so we can see if you made something circular

Comment: Ok so if the user is not admin it should go to home, but that one also have a authguard for user, will it do the same ?

Comment: The AuthGuard is to verify if the user has logged in or not on the login page, once logged in the second Guard is to see if the user admin tries to enter home it will send it to admin and the same with the user.

Comment: Guards  are not executed in a specific order. So you might hit the the wrong guard first. Since you have the authguard from angular fire i bet its slower to execute than you user and admin roles. Add some console log at the redirect area and see if it just continues to bounce between the two guards.

Comment: Oh, it's true the guard admin was running without stopping. What solution could apply for this? Should I add the check whether you are logged in or not inside the Guards Admin and User ?

Comment: You could but if you do i wouldnt use the authguard from angular/fire else you would double check the same auth. If you use claims you can use that with the authguard

Comment: Yes, the idea would be that if I have the problem, I would remove the authguard and add that check inside the Admin/UserGuard. That would be a good option right?

Comment: It looks like you're guarding the `home` route with a guard which redirects to `home` on failure…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for this situation is, remove authGurad and use UserService in each guard to check user is logged in:

RoleAdminGuard:

```js
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const isLoggedIn = this.userService.isLoggedIn();
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
    const rol = localStorage.getItem('rolUser');

    if (rol !== 'admin'){
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And you should do same thing for RoleUserGuard with the different condition (role).

Or

We can use user dictionary like this in the UserService.
UserService:

```js
userAccess= {
  home: 'user',
  admin: 'admin'
}
```

And just use one guard (RoleGuard)
RoleGuard:

```js
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const isLoggedIn = this.userService.isLoggedIn();
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
    const rol = localStorage.getItem('rolUser');
    const userAccess = this.userService.userAccess[next.url]
    if (rol !== userAccess) {
      const navigateTo = rol === 'admin' ? '/admin' : '/home';
      this.router.navigate([navigateTo]);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I hope this help you.